# Javascript newb - Unknown Name Error

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and trying to replicate something that I have working in VbScript and I'm getting an error and I'm not sure why, as most examples I've found online seem to be written very similarly.

```
var profile = [],
    count = 0,
    size = 840;

while (count < size) {
    profile[count] = BasisWeight.DataValue("QCS_Pro_BW.PROFILEA.DATAARRAY[" + count + "]");
    count++;
};
```

I'm getting an "Unknown Name" error for "profile[count]" in the while loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `BasisWeight.DataValue`?

Comment: what is this `BasisWeight.DataValue("QCS_Pro_BW.PROFILEA.DATAARRAY[" + count + "]");`

Comment: Your code works just fine. https://jsfiddle.net/87rw2fze/ Of course I had to replace your function with a value

Comment: where is this method defined -> BasisWeight.DataValue

Comment: This is for a DCS system HMI Display and that is how I read data from parameters in the control system. Hmmm. I just took that out and changed it to "profile[count] = count;" on that line to see if I could just read incrementing numbers into the array and now I get different error, that doesn't seem to be related to this line (error is for the main jgplot javascript that I'm trying to use - maybe the array isn't populating?)

Comment: Ah, ok then. I thought it was barking about the profile[count] - I guess it's not liking the datavalue access item. Thanks all.